# nagios how to monitor remote host by shell scripts?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, nagios, nrpe

Do not install nrpe, but want in the Nagios control server writing shell scripts to control the remote host,like a process, the database state. can achieve? How to write the script?

Comment: What to you mean by control? Do you want do perform checks or trigger an action depending on a check result?

Comment: I mean that in the Nagios server monitoring remote host, instead of installing nrpe, achieve the purpose of monitoring

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to nrpe is to use the `[check_by_ssh][1]` plugin. It will connect via SSH and execute the specified plugin (or script).

Example for the check_free_mem plugin

```
define command{
    command_name    check_ssh_mem
    command_line    $USER1$/check_by_ssh -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C "$USER1$/check_free_mem -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$"
}
```